# How to get WPF application to break in code?

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net

When debugging in .NET, I really enjoy being able to step directly into my code when an error is triggered at a certain location. When programming a WPF application, however, I can't seem to access this feature.

Consider this simple program:

```
sub breakMe()
   dim badObject as Object = nothing
   getObjectString(badObject)
 end sub

sub getObjectString(whatObj as object)
   whatObj.toString
 end sub
```

If this were a winforms project, the debugger would break right on the "whatObj.toString" line and I could step into the call stack there and jump around into any prior procedures and check object values throughout. With WPF, however, there is an unhandled exception triggered that makes this impossible.

I've read many, many examples of ways that you can add handlers to WPF which allow you to custom handle exceptions so that you can view the relevant stack trace. While helpful, this is still not nearly as good as being actually able to step into the code exactly where it breaks and view object values.

You could add try blocks to achieve the desired result, but that would obviously be impractical to do throughout the project, and it seems like there should be an easy way to do this. Perhaps by forcing the debugger to simply bypass the handlers for the WPF graphical components?

Comment: You are doing something horribly, horribly wrong. Breakpoints and even exceptions work the same in WPF as they do everywhere else

Comment: Recommend to double-check your exceptions settings and make sure you're set to break-on-throw for NullReferenceException (and any other exception type where you want to break when it's thrown).  Otherwise, maybe you were relying on the absence of a high-level handler so that the exceptions were uncaught, but now one is in place.  If you break on throw, you can also step forward to find out where the handler is; if it's in your own code, you might be able to get rid of it (possibly conditionally on being a debug build).

Comment: Thanks, Craig, that definitely solved the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Exception is most likely thrown by some error in your XAML, not in your C# code.

To learn how to get more information on errors in XAML read this article:

[How to: Display WPF Trace Information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-display-wpf-trace-information)